# Java TCP and UDP server working simultaneously

Tags: java, tcp, udp

I'm trying to build a program able to have a TCP server connecting to a client on one port while also being able to pass and listen for data in UDP packets on other ports.

I'm acting as a TCP server and getting commands from a TCP client and then passing them by UDP to other devices. I also have to listen in UDP for the responses from the devices and then pass them back to the TCP client. I have been trying to achieve this by creating 2 threads, one for connecting to the TCP client  while  constantly listening for UDP packets on the other thread with a different port.

It works fine when getting data from the TCP client and sending them to the UDP devices.
But when I try to collect the results from the UDP devices and sending them back to the TCP client. The program isn't able to send the data back immediately. It's stuck waiting for the TCP client to send data. Which means I have a vector queue filled with results but I have to wait for the TCP client to communicate with me in order to send back the results.

Is there a way to notify the TCP thread to send data whenever there is data in the vector?

```
public class TCPUDP2 {

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();  
final protected static int udplistenport=1002;
final protected static int tcplistenport=1001;
private static Vector<String> udprecv=new Vector();     //UDP result queue


public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {   //convert byte[] to string
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {               //Convert string to byte[]
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

     Thread udplisten = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
                try {


                    DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(udplistenport);
                    System.out.println("UDP Listening");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);


                    while (true) {

                      dsocket.receive(packet);

                      byte[] newbuffer= new byte[packet.getLength()];

                      for(int i =0;i<packet.getLength();i++)
                        newbuffer[i]=buffer[i];


                      System.out.println(" UDP from "+packet.getAddress()+" "+bytesToHex(newbuffer)+" "+new java.util.Date());
                      udprecv.add(bytesToHex(newbuffer));
                      System.out.println(udprecv);


                      //String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
                      //System.out.println(msg);  


                      // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
                      packet.setLength(buffer.length);
                    }
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                  }
         }
     }; 

     udplisten.start();

     Thread tcpplisten = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
             System.out.println("TCP Listening");
             ByteArrayOutputStream serverinput=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

             try{

                 ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(tcplistenport);     // establish tcp server


                 for(;;) {

                  Socket sc  = ss.accept();               
                 System.out.println(sc.getLocalSocketAddress().toString()+" "+new java.util.Date());   
                 OutputStream os = sc.getOutputStream();    
                 InputStream in = sc.getInputStream(); 
                 int len=0;
                 byte[] buf=new byte[2048];   

                 while( !(udprecv.isEmpty())){
                    String first=udprecv.firstElement();
                    byte[] tcpsend=hexStringToByteArray(first);
                   os.write(tcpsend);//Send to Client
                   os.flush();
                   System.out.println("Sent by TCP "+bytesToHex(tcpsend)+" "+new java.util.Date());
                   udprecv.removeElementAt(0);
                }


                 while ((len = in.read(buf))>=0)
                 {
                     serverinput.write(buf, 0, len);


                    System.out.println("From TCP "+bytesToHex(serverinput.toByteArray())+" "+sc.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
                    MessageCreator cannonball=new MessageCreator("02","003F", bytesToHex(serverinput.toByteArray()));
                    byte[] cmd= cannonball.create(); 

                    String udpip="127.0.0.1";
                    int udpport=8888;
                    UDPSender cannon =new UDPSender(udpip,udpport,cmd); 
                    System.out.println("Sent by UDP "+bytesToHex(cmd)+" "+udpip+":"+udpport);
                    cannon.fire();


                    serverinput.reset();  

                    while( !(udprecv.isEmpty())){
                        String first=udprecv.firstElement();
                        byte[] tcpsend=hexStringToByteArray(first);
                       os.write(tcpsend);//Send to Client
                       os.flush();
                       System.out.println("Sent by TCP "+bytesToHex(tcpsend));
                       udprecv.removeElementAt(0);                                                                              
                    }

                 }


                // os.close();                                // Close stream
                // sc.close();                                // Shutdown TCP server

             }
             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.err.println(e);

             }


         }
     };
     tcpplisten.start();


   }
   }
```

Comment: I think you should work on your design. If you have one Thread listening on TCP, you can still send over the same socket instance from another Thread. But you'll need to keep the sockets in a place, where a different thread can reference them.

Comment: Does that mean that the TCP connection has to be interrupted or disconnected whenever another thread is trying to use it?

Comment: Why do you think it has to? It doesn' t make much sense to read with more than one thread. But you can send from another thread at the same time.

Comment: I've been trying to pass data from the UDP listening thread to the TCP server thread but whatever I Try seems to interrupt the TCP connection.